# How do I learn-by-practicing digital circuits - MIPS R2000 (or similar) processor or board?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, digital-logic, pcb-design, mips

I already do have a book which I am studying for a university course. I've searched online to buy a development kit for MIPS R2000 (or similar) and have been suggested the MIPS CI20. Don't know if or how that would be suitable for practicing. I would like to get my hands dirty with:

- building a simple processor (or at least designing and get it shipped
  to me)
- understanding how a board is made, how all the pieces are put together and if possible, learn, technically, to remove/add/substitute parts of a board (buying and using equipment for soldering on boards).

Where do I start from? What do I buy first?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. This question is likely to be closed for a few reasons: it's _primarily opinion based_, _too broad_, and _unclear what you're asking_. If you have a specific question, it will generally be answered. Have a look at the [tour] in the meantime :)

Comment: You know the saying to learn to crawl before flying supersonic fighter planes?

Comment: I wonder if you're using the word _processor_ in a way that no one else does. To you it seems to mean the whole board, or do you really want to build a _processor_ and have it shipped to you?

Comment: If you want to design and build a processor, you don't want a preexisting processor, you want an FPGA. But I think that's probably very far from the place to start with this sort of thing.

Comment: The second question (board construction) is *much* easier to learn than the first. You should take a general electronics course then look at PCB design - there are various adequate free courses on this around on the net.

Comment: You should probably start with something simple and current like a small ARM Cortex MCU or maybe an AVR or for larger software stacks a raspberry pi. If you really want a MIPS core the most accessable place they survive is in wifi routers and related IOT platforms, for example the Linkit MT7688

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have some misconceptions about how dev kits work. A dev kit for a certain processor architecture isn't a tool for developing a new or similar processor, it's for designing a system that includes the said processor (or another member of its architecture family).

Now, if you want to learn how a processor works internally, there are some basics you need to cover first. I often point to https://www.nand2tetris.org when people ask me about where to start. This course introduces many important concepts of digital design. It even includes a simple *Hardware Description Language* or HDL that you use for designing (and simulating) everything from simple logic gates to your own CPU and computer system.

If you want to design and test your own logic circuits, there are basically two options. Either you get a breadboard and some number of 74-series ICs and discrete components (resistors, caps, etc.) to experiment with, or you get an FPGA board that lets you program your logic circuits onto an FPGA. I don't really work with FPGAs, but people tell me this is a good starting point: https://www.nandland.com

Actually designing and producing your own CPU chip is a very complex (and expensive) process, that requires a lot of knowledge about semiconductors physics, lithography, production processes, etc.

If you really want to design and test your own CPU, an FPGA is your best and affordable option.

Finally, designing and producing PCBs is a whole topic on its own. There are a lot of things to consider before and during the design of a PCB, here is a simple introduction: https://www.edn.com/design/pc-board/4424239/PCB-design-basics

If you get yourself a good breadboard and/or FPGA board for experimenting, you should be able to get a long way along before you need an actual custom PCB. There are people who build whole simple computers on breadboards. It will also keep your costs down since you'll only need a few tools like a standard soldering iron, a multimeter, pliers, etc.

So, the `tl:dr` version:

1. Learn the basics of digital design (boolean algebra, basic circuit analysis, etc.)
2. Experiment with basic logic gates like NOT, OR, etc.
3. Build simple advanced components like latches and flip-flops
4. Keep improving them into registers, ALU, etc. until you have all components for a simple CPU
5. Verify your CPU design with the help of an FPGA and/or an HDL like VHDL or SystemVerilog.